# What does this picture say in circular Gallifreyan?

Tags: doctor-who, gallifrey

[image] Can someone please figure out what the circular drawing on the picture on the right side of the TARDIS (which I suspect is writing in Gallifreyan as one of their writing types is circular) might say?

Comment: There is no usable Gallifreyan writing system. The design team just make stuff up as they go that looks cool.

Comment: “$60 or best offer. Please contact the artist. Swaps considered, 420 friendly.”

Answer (score 6):

According to [this](https://www.instagram.com/p/BLh4VzUAAw1/?taken-by=louwolgast) Instagram post by the original artist, Lou Wolgast, this was a tattoo concept. As seen in the comments, he believes it's the name of the client.

Comment: I believe it's written in Sherman's Gallifreyan, a popular fan-developed system documented at http://shermansplanet.com/storage/Gallifreyan.pdf (PDF, obviously).  I can't be bothered to translate it given that it's "just" someone's name.

Answer (score 2):

Circular Gallifreyan cannot be translated effectively, in fact, it's nigh-on impossible. The exact spacing for the lettering is extremely difficult to be measured correctly, and while a series of circles can mean someone's name, one little error can result in the meaning becoming something like sitting on your keyboard. Some day, it may be answered effectively, but for now, it cannot be definitively answered. Sorry to disappoint.